# Only allowing a loop of odd numbers in a function

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

I am teaching myself python but am getting really stuck on this question. It asks to "Write a function which accepts as input a list of odd numbers. Loop over the list of odd numbers and turn each into an even number. Store each even number in a new list and return that new list."

I'm happy with the latter part of the question but struggling with only allowing the input to be odd numbers.

Here's what I've written so far, it works for any odd list you submit e.g. ([1,3,5]) and it works when you start with an even number e.g. ([2,3,5]) but I can't get it to work for when the even number is mid way through the list e.g. ([1,2,3]) - I want it to print this can't be done.

```
def odd_to_even(x):
for i in x:
    if i %2 == 0:
        print('This is not an odd number')
        break
    else:
        list = []
        for n in x:
            list.append(n -1)
        return list
```

Comment: Why do you need to deal with that case? The spec says you get a list of odd numbers, so you can assume that to always be true, unless it's asked you to reject otherwise. Also you have a weird double-looping thing going on (both `for i in x` and `for n in x`).

Comment: That problem statement doesn't actually say that you need to reject even inputs, does it? I mean, you can, but if the API just says "provide a list of odd numbers" and the caller provides even numbers, that's at least partially on them. Python: "We're all adults here"

Comment: It sort of depends on how you interpret the word "accepts". Does that include "reject"?

Comment: FWIW: `if any(i % 2 == 0 for i in x): raise ValueError`

Comment: @deceze I'd say only if it says *"**only** accepts"*

Comment: @jonrsharpe Agreed. I'd throw in the input validation as a bonus anyway. ;)

Comment: Thank you everyone -  it now works! Even if "accept" doesn't mean I needed to reject the even cases, I wanted to anyway :) I would like to know how my double-looping is weird though as I would like to improve this too!

Comment: BTW, you should never use `list` as a variable name as that shadows the built-in `list` type. It's not an error to do that (so Python won't print an error message), but it's confusing to others reading your code, and it can lead to bugs that _will_ cause mysterious error messages to be printed.

Comment: Updated my answer to, hopefully, explain about the problem of the double loop.

Answer (score 3):

I would agree with the comments by @jonrsharpe, @ShadowRanger, and @deceze that you probably don't need to include testing, but it wouldn't hurt.  I'll use @deceze's line for that check here.  Remember, you must declare your list **outside** the loop using it, or the loop will reset it each iteration.  Even better to change the names to make things clearer.

```
def odd_to_even(input_list):
    if any(i % 2 == 0 for i in input_list): raise ValueError
    output_list = []
    for i in input_list:
        output_list.append(i - 1)
    return output_list
```

To incorporate @deceze's good one-liner and keep the validation:

```
def odd_to_even(input_list):
    if any(i % 2 == 0 for i in input_list): raise ValueError
    return [i - 1 for i in input_list]
```

You asked in a comment what is weird about the double looping, so I'd like to add a small explanation for that here.  Sometimes you want to have a loop within a loop, but this was not one of those cases.  You have a single list, and looping over it one time is sufficient in this case for you to:

1. Determine whether all numbers inside the list are odd (validate the list)
2. Take each number, modify it, and add it to your output list

By looping a second time inside your first loop, you would end up looping over the list for each time you looped over the list.  Maybe that phrasing is confusing.  Let's say your input list was `[1, 3, 5]`.  By using a loop inside a loop, you'd end up creating a new list to output 3 times, because you'd create your output one time for each item in the input.  I hope that helps clear it up for you.

Comment: This may not be beginner friendly, but… `return [i - 1 for i in x]`…

Comment: Or if you want to accept both odd and even, and just ensure they're even when you return (passing even isn't an error, they just remain unchanged): `return [i & ~1 for i in x]`